# Is there any way collapsing an container in scroll view using smartface app studio?

Tags: smartface.io

I am having many containers in the scroll view. And in which few of them should be visible false and collapse when there is no content in it.

I tried with adjusting top and height for all the containers. But, i not working in all cases and many combinations of conditions to calculate and apply top and heights.

Is there any way i can achieve this in smart-face app studio?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is a way. I don't know about your design but, if you can set your scrollview design as in the image below

[image]

And now, when you change the visibility of the inner objects they will be visible or invisible. 
For example, if you have 3 containers, you don't want the second one to be seen for a special reason, then when you change it's visibility to false, only first and third containers will be seen.